# Armenian text with some words in English

Tags: languages

I need to write Armenian text with some of the words in English. However, when I use armtex package or the code below, I get the English words with Armenian letters. How can I fix it?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1,OT6]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section*{Տեքստ}
Արևը՝ անգլերեն Sun, մեր համաստեղության միակ աստղն է։
\end{document}
```

Comment: From a discussion found on the net: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15900              `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1,OT6]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage {xltxtra, polyglossia}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage {english}
\newfontface \armfont [Script=Armenian]{DejaVuSans}
\begin {document}


\section*{\armfont{{Տեքստ}
Արևը՝ անգլերեն Sun, մեր համաստեղության միակ աստղն է։}}
Some Text
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly with XeTex and
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! But use the code of TivV, its contribution is better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Armenian Wikibooks](https://hy.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D4%BC%D5%A1%D5%8F%D5%A5%D4%BD/%D4%B2%D5%A1%D6%80%D6%87_%D5%A1%D5%B7%D5%AD%D5%A1%D6%80%D5%B0), it's (probably, I can't read Armenian) a good guide.

A couple of things can be improved from Annie's comment:

1. Do not load `inputenc` and `fontenc` if you use LuaTeX or XeTeX. `fontspec` is enough.
2. `xltxtra` should already be incorporated in `fontspec`, you probably don't have to load it.

And a suggestion:

Right now you have to put `\armfont{}` around your Armenian text. If Armenian is going to be the language you write in the most, I suggest you do this: Use `\setmainfont[Script=Armenian]{DejaVuSans}` instead of `\newfontface...`, that way all text will be interpreted as [Script=Armenian] per default. Then change `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` to `\setotherlanguage{english}` and add `\newfontfamily\englishfont{DejaVuSans}`. If you then want to write english, use `\textenglish{hello}`.

So it would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Script=Armenian]{DejaVuSans}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{DejaVuSans}

\begin{document}
Տեքստ Արևը՝ անգլերեն Sun, մեր համաստեղության միակ աստղն է։

\textenglish{hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks TIVV, I tried a possible solution but with many difficulties because I am aware of my little experience. Your code is more precise!